# how to integrate Tank auth on a website?

Tags: php, codeigniter, login-control, tankauth

I've installed codeigniter on my server and made Tank auth work fine, too. now I want to know how to access Tank auth from my php pages. do I have to use `include` function so the login is placed inside my original php page or there is a better way how to do that??

I also want to show the login and log out buttons on my php pages.

any idea or clue to achieve that?

Thanks

**Update #1**
I believe that I can't create Tank auth session out of codeigniter, so how can I integrate my php pages in this CMS? please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: You want to access it in a controller? don't use you just do `$this->tank_auth`?

Comment: I want to access the Tank auth through my web pages that are not located in the codeigniter CMS. It is like the library Tank auth is going to be a connection to the my site visitors and my php pages out of the CMS.

Comment: Ah ok, would have been clearer if you had said that. Not too sure...i'mt not familiar with CI or tank auth.

Comment: Thanks @Flukey for your comments. I thought maybe I can include the library to my php pages and add their session on each page, and done.... but I'm not so sure about it. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm also this time going to answer my own question since I found the solution. maybe it is not the best answer, but I made it work in my side. To make the Tank Auth system work on other pages, the pages have to be placed in View folder in codeigniter framework so that an admin can gives permissions to do whatsoever in order to access the pages. Also, from the controller folder pages have to be identified in the same Tank Auth controller page so that the system works together wih any new page. I tried to place the pages out of the framework, but it didn't work Codeiginiter can't define out source variables.  I get a lot of error as a result of that. I hope anyone find this useful. Thanks.